# My MySQLi query gives error but i can't find out thats wrong with it

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working with a mysql query to select data from multiple tables using LEFT OUTER JOIN. Now i get the following error when i exequte the query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'wg.werkbon_global_id = wk.werkbon_klant_globalid  LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN users AS u' at line 16

Only the problem is that i can't find out what's wrong with my query.

PHP Query:

```
$query = '
    SELECT
        wg.werkbon_global_id AS id,
        wg.werkbon_global_status AS status,
        wg.werkbon_global_date_lastedit AS date,
        usr.user_firstname AS monteur_vn,
        usr.user_insertion AS monteur_tv,
        usr.user_lastname AS monteur_an,
        wg.werkbon_global_type AS type,
        wg.werkbon_global_layout AS layout,
        wg.werkbon_global_werkzaamheden AS werkzaamheden,
        wg.werkbon_global_opmerkingen AS opmerkingen,
        wk.werkbon_klant_nummer AS klantnr
    FROM
        werkbon_klant AS wk
    LEFT OUTER JOIN werkbon_global AS wg
        wg.werkbon_global_id = wk.werkbon_klant_globalid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS usr
        usr.user_id = wg.werkbon_global_monteur_finish
    WHERE
        wk.werkbon_klant_nummer = '.$db->Quote($klantid).'
    ORDER BY id ASC;
$result = $db->loadAssoc($query);
```

I think my problem has something todo with left outer join but what?

Comment: You have a missing quote `'` - most likely `ORDER BY id ASC';`

Comment: Where do i miss that Quote? not there. i checked the query withoud ORDER BY

Comment: Reload my comment above. I edited it - `ORDER BY id ASC';` - edit: a mix of, as per Arkascha's comment which has been deleted. double-edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the ON operator in your joins!

The correct syntax for a join is:

```
SELECT * FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON condition WHERE...
```

Comment: Plus the missing quote.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. Thanks. Not any quote is missing working now.

Comment: @Paules Are you saying that the quote wasn't "part" of the problem? If so, I find that rather hard to believe. 3 quotes is a mismatch and would surely throw an error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Most likely that quote was a copy and paste problem here, not an issue in the real code. Otherwise no query would have been executed at all. Anyhows: the cited error messages clearly points to the position of the error...

Comment: @arkascha I understand. I just take posted code for face value ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "
 SELECT
    wg.werkbon_global_id AS id,
    wg.werkbon_global_status AS status,
    wg.werkbon_global_date_lastedit AS date,
    usr.user_firstname AS monteur_vn,
    usr.user_insertion AS monteur_tv,
    usr.user_lastname AS monteur_an,
    wg.werkbon_global_type AS type,
    wg.werkbon_global_layout AS layout,
    wg.werkbon_global_werkzaamheden AS werkzaamheden,
    wg.werkbon_global_opmerkingen AS opmerkingen,
    wk.werkbon_klant_nummer AS klantnr
FROM
    werkbon_klant AS wk
LEFT OUTER JOIN werkbon_global AS wg
    wg.werkbon_global_id = wk.werkbon_klant_globalid
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS usr
    usr.user_id = wg.werkbon_global_monteur_finish
WHERE
    wk.werkbon_klant_nummer = '.$db->Quote($klantid).'
ORDER BY id ASC";
```

$result = $db->loadAssoc($query);

Make sure there isn't missing quote

Answer (score 0):

Problem soved thanks to arkascha

The fixed query is now:

```
$query = '
    SELECT
        wg.werkbon_global_id AS id,
        wg.werkbon_global_status AS status,
        wg.werkbon_global_date_lastedit AS date,
        usr.user_firstname AS monteur_vn,
        usr.user_insertion AS monteur_tv,
        usr.user_lastname AS monteur_an,
        wg.werkbon_global_type AS type,
        wg.werkbon_global_layout AS layout,
        wg.werkbon_global_werkzaamheden AS werkzaamheden,
        wg.werkbon_global_opmerkingen AS opmerkingen,
        wk.werkbon_klant_nummer AS klantnr
    FROM
        werkbon_klant AS wk
    LEFT OUTER JOIN werkbon_global AS wg ON
        wg.werkbon_global_id = wk.werkbon_klant_globalid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS usr ON
        usr.user_id = wg.werkbon_global_monteur_finish
    WHERE
        wk.werkbon_klant_nummer = '.$db->Quote($klantid).'
    ORDER BY id ASC';
$result = $db->loadAssoc($query);
```

@fred i don't need to add quotes by column names. You only need to add quotes by string/blob values.
@johny my $db->Quote() function will add qoutes automaticly. I don't need to add them and put everything in quote's.

Thanks all for help.